# Writing to CSV from nba_api not separating per row

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to pull previous NBA games from the python NBA_API and my formatting isn't working out as I need it to. I'd like every row from the data stream to be separated out onto every from from the column

```
import nba_api
import requests
import csv
from nba_api.stats.static import teams
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamefinder
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamelog
season = leaguegamelog.LeagueGameLog("00")

nba_teams = teams.get_teams()
seasonGames = season.get_data_frames()[0]
seasonGames.head()
print(seasonGames.TEAM_NAME)

with open('NBAStats.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['team_name','team_id','game_id']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file,     fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',')

    writer.writeheader()
    for TEAM_NAME in seasonGames['TEAM_NAME']:
        writer.writerow({'team_name': seasonGames["TEAM_NAME"],'team_id': seasonGames["TEAM_ID"],'game_id': seasonGames["GAME_ID"]})
print("done")
```

This is what the output looks like: [image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpokg.jpg

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what do you want. Could you provide more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
import csv
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamelog
season = leaguegamelog.LeagueGameLog("00")

seasonGames = season.get_data_frames()[0]

with open('NBAStats.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['team_name','team_id','game_id']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter=',', lineterminator='\n')

    writer.writeheader()

    for group in seasonGames.groupby("TEAM_NAME"):
        TEAM_NAME, group_df = group
        for ix in group_df.index:
            writer.writerow({'team_name': group_df.loc[ix, "TEAM_NAME"],
                             'team_id': group_df.loc[ix, "TEAM_ID"],
                             'game_id': group_df.loc[ix, "GAME_ID"]})
print("done")
```

[image]

Or use a simpler way:

```
import csv
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import leaguegamelog
season = leaguegamelog.LeagueGameLog("00")

seasonGames = season.get_data_frames()[0]

opDF = seasonGames.sort_values(by=["TEAM_NAME", "GAME_ID"])[["TEAM_NAME", "TEAM_ID", "GAME_ID"]]
opDF.columns = [["team_name", "team_id", "game_id"]]
opDF.to_csv('NBAStats.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: YES! Thank you so much

Comment: @jimmyboi If you find this answer helpful, please consider accept it. Thanks! :)